# UIViewController view disappears when I change a view frame iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8

This code with iOS 7 works fine, but when it runs in XCode 6 & iOS8 simulator, the view disappears (UIViewController viewWillDisappear is called) after I make a small change to the self.webview.frame.  This happens when I select the "Edit" option from the actionSheet.  However, when I tap the webView and notify/call keyboardWillShow:, it does not disappear.  This UIViewController was presented by the rootViewController with modalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet  I'd appreciate any help.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSString *title = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Edit"]){
        [self switchModeTo:@"Edit"];
    }
}

- (void)switchModeTo:(NSString *)mode{
    if([mode isEqualToString:@"Edit"]){
        self.isEditMode = YES;
        [self.btnApply setHidden:NO];
        [self.btnMore setHidden:YES];
        CGRect frame = [self.webview frame];
        frame.origin.y = 44;
        frame.size.height = 492;
        [self.webview setFrame:frame];
    }
}

- (void)keyBoardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif{
    [self switchModeTo:@"Edit"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problem.  I attempted to present a modal view controller triggered from an action sheet.  The modal view was presented, and then it was immediately dismissed.

I created another test case, and received the following message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <ModalViewController: 0x78fbadd0>  on <MainViewController: 0x78fa71c0> which is already presenting (null)
```

It turned out that the action sheet popover was interfering with the view controller's ability to present another modal view controller.  As with your example, if I triggered the same code from something other than an action sheet (in my case, a button), it worked fine.

To resolve the issue, I simply introduced a small delay to give the action sheet popover a chance to get out of the way, as in this example:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if ( buttonIndex != actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex ) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(showModalView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
    }
}

- (void)showModalView
{
    ModalViewController* modalVC = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:modalVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```